# Using AJAX to run PHP code

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have written some JavaScript code that will read from the Google Maps API and get a list of JSON objects. It will then convert each JSON object into an XML object. A co-worker needs this list converted to XML and then appended to an existing XML file  and then save it to our server. So I wrote some PHP code to do that.

Now this is my first time working with PHP but I managed to write that PHP code easily enough. The next thing I am trying to do is write some javascript to run the PHP file and also send the XML object over to the PHP where it can append and save the XML. I figured I would use jQuery's `$.ajax` function. I started using a simple example trying to echo a string into some `<pre>` tags. So here is my code:

Javascript (Lies within index.php)

```
<script>
    var scriptString = 'THIS IS MY STRING';
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
        $.ajax(
        {
            method:'get',
        url:'index.php',
        data:
        {
            'myString': scriptString
        }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

PHP & HTML (also lies within index.php)

```
<button type="button" id="clickMe">CLICK ME TO RUN PHP</button>
<pre>
    <?php
        echo $_GET['myString'];
    ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: myString should show up in the <pre> tags once you click the clickMe div/button. It doesn't do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Don't include `=` in your data variable names (just say `'myString': scriptString`)
- Always include the form submission method for `$.ajax` ( `method: 'get'` )
- In the PHP code, instead of `$myString`, use `$_GET['myString']`
- Consider using a `<button>` instead of a `<div>` to send the data to the server - this is more standard.

But most importantly:

- You're not actually doing anything with the returned data!  You also need a `success` function in the `$.ajax` options that does something with the data from the server.

Try this code:

(JavaScript)

```
var scriptString = 'THIS IS MY STRING';
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'index.php',
      data: {
        'myString': scriptString,
        'ajax': true
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#data').text(data);
      }
    });
});
```

(PHP and HTML)

```
<?php
if ($_GET['ajax']) {
  echo $_GET['myString'];
} else {
?>
<button type="button" id="clickMe">CLICK ME TO RUN PHP</button>
<pre id="data"></pre>
<?php } ?>
```

Note that the PHP code will now do different things based on whether or not it is handling an AJAX request.  For AJAX requests, you don't want to return the HTML for the page - just the data you're interested in.  For this reason, it might be better to have two pages: one `index.php` page, and one `ajax.php` page which handles AJAX requests.

Also, in this simple examle, you could have just used a plain HTML form, which wouldn't require any JavaScript or AJAX.

Comment: You forgot to mention that @MikeNolan needs a `success` function to do "something" with the returned data.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, either passing that as a parameter or using .done(success)

Comment: The thing is when I echo that data (which it would on the clicking of that button) it should show up in the <pre> tags right? Or is there a command that I need to execute in the PHP to send the data back to the client?

Comment: Derp.  Thanks Matt.  It's the simple stuff that gets me.

Comment: Mike - that's not how AJAX works.  There's no way for the browser to know that "I just received this data, so I'm going to merge it with the existing HTML".  You have to write JavaScript to do something with the data returned from the server.  See my updated answer.

Comment: One of the best answers I've seen

Comment: Still excellent information after all these years. Got me out of a bind with little effort, thank you!